# Which is best embedded database for java?

Tags: java, embedded-database

I have to develop embedded project in java and for that I need good embedded database.

Features i need are:

1) relational database
2) GUI interface

Can anyone suggest me good database?

Thanks

Comment: hey guys why are you giving minus? what is wrong here

Comment: Hi Deval! The problem with your question is that it is a discussion-oriented question without a clear answer, and those are not for SO. Please consult the FAQ for more info.

Comment: Without knowing what kind of data base features you need, it's really hard to offer any answer.

Comment: http://w-shadow.com/blog/2009/02/25/top-4-free-embedded-databases/  
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_database

Comment: i have edited my questions in which i have mention some features which i need

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Either

**HSQLDB** - Used by OpenOffice, tested and stable. It's easy to use. If you want to edit your db-data, you can just open the file and edit the insert statements.
or

**H2** - Said to be faster (by the developer, who originally designed hsqldb, too)
Which one you use is up to you, depending how much performance and how much stability you need.

The developer of H2 has put up a nice performance evaluation:
http://www.h2database.com/html/performance.html

[see more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462923/java-embedded-databases-comparison)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462923/java-embedded-databases-comparison

Comment: You copied [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/463355/839733) answer verbatim, without any attribution to the original author. Coulda just used the duplicate button.