# Create an internal Database for Java EE?

Tags: java, android, database, hibernate, jakarta-ee

I'm creating a web application, possibly using Maven, Spring and Hibernate.

I need to create a database for the application which will obviously hold some data, however as I need to send the application to someone once it is finished so that they can run it on their machine, I am not sure how to create the DB.

I have developed Android appliations previously where I have used sqlite to create an internal database, and I was wondering if there is anything that I could use similar?

Or will I have to use something like phpmyadmin?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Do you mean you need an embedded database (i.e. a DBMS that runs along with your webapplication, without an external server)?

Comment: Yeah exactly, I read something about apache derby - maybe that could be suitable?

Comment: I have no experience about embedded databases, you may start looking at [this (very old) question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/462923/java-embedded-databases-comparison), or search for newer ones.