# Best way to create a database in a billing program for a common user

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, database, cross-platform

I am using java to make a billing program for a company. For my (poor) experience I think that the best way to keep a database active, which will be accessed and modified constantly, is using SQL.
But my question arises when they have to use this program in their own PC.

To use a SQL database is it necessary to the user PC install a SQL server in their PC? (bearing in mind that they want to use the program without the need of internet). Any PC with raw Windows/Ubuntu (or any similar OS) is compatible with SQL databases? If it is not compatible which method would you use to make this kind of database?

Comment: You're going to have to think this situation through carefully: do you intend for all users to be sharing a common database, or do you really intend for users to maintain personal, independent databases? As written, your issue is far too broad for Stack Overflow. There are way too many answers given your vague specifications.

Comment: since you have cross-platform in the tags please note that sql-server is available for ms operating system only so it is not cross platform at all; if this is a requirement then sql-server it is not the right choice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want each user has his own installation and database you can consider some **java embedded database**, for example HSQLDB or H2.

see this links:

[Java Embedded Databases Comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462923/java-embedded-databases-comparison)

http://hsqldb.org/

Simplifying - embedded database means that database server runs within your java application, so user **do not have** to install additional software.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a self-contained SQL database such as [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/).