# What database i used for java offline application

Tags: java, database, offlineapps

I want to develop application.which is offline(runs on single pc).Which database i should use so that when I create exe of my project it will automatically included in it.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you're looking for an embedded database. [Here is a thread on Java embedded databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462923/java-embedded-databases-comparison). I use Apache Derby, mostly because it's easy to use with NetBeans.

Answer (score 2):

You can look to the H2 database, no db server is needed!
http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use `MS-Access`. That works totally offline and you can include it in your project. It is also easy to work with MS-Access & Java.

Hope this helps.