# java > store large amounts of data

Tags: java, database, large-data

I am currently making an app where I will need to store large amounts of data,
between 4000 and 7000 user names and an equal amount of register dates.

How do you recommend me doing it?

Comment: That's nowhere near "large" amounts of data, so do it anyway you want and know how.

Comment: 4k to 7k records is not a large amount of data. Just go for a NoSQL or SQL databases.

Comment: Just use a simple database table and get use to doing it that way for when you actually get into dealing with real amounts of data.

Answer (score 0):

You want a database of some sort. The DB can be either embedded (runs inside your Java process) or stand-alone (runs as a separate daemon process, either on the same machine or on a different one). With an embedded DB, your app will be much simpler to configure; you'll lose a lot of features, but your use case sounds pretty simple, so I wouldn't worry about that right now.

Also, the DB can be table-oriented (SQL) or not (what's known as NoSQL; I don't like that term, because it's not very descriptive, but I don't have anything better). Any of those would work in your case, but I would recommend an SQL-based DB just because SQL is a skill that every programmer needs.

Based on personal experience, I would tell you to use HSQLDB. Also see: [Java Embedded Databases Comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462923/java-embedded-databases-comparison)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a DBMS of course.

Here is a good tutorial for building up an application with a database: http://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/