# bundled JavaDB in java 8 setup

Tags: java, sql, eclipse, derby, javadb

I've read that in Java 8, derby DB embedded driver in bundled(included). Is that true and if so how to refer to it in eclipse?

Comment: And where did you read that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37828325/how-to-include-database-into-my-app
last answer

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/support/overview.html

Answer (score 1):

According to the technical notes (http://docs.oracle.com/javadb/index_jdk8.html) Java DB (Apache Derby) is only bundled (included) with the Java Development Kit (JDK 7 and JDK 8).

It does not come bundled (included) with the Java Standard Edition Java Runtime installations.

If you have a JDK installed, one way to access it from Eclipse is to add the /db/lib/derby.jar file into a user-defined library, and add that library to the build path of your project(s).  This is the easiest, but highly discouraged as it will be hard to resolve these types of dependencies when the application needs to be launched outside of Eclipse.

Once you are comfortable with JavaDB, I would recommend that you use Maven/Gradle to manage building and deploying, as well as using Apache Derby.