# How can a Java app create and manage a DB locally for a user?

Tags: java, database, sqlite

I'm working on a to-do list app in Java as a learning exercise in databases. I'd like to write the app agnostic to a theoretical user's setup and not assume they have anything like MySQL installed. How can a Java application create and manage a local database, in this case to hold things like tasks, deadlines, etc? Is something like SQLite the only way to go for local?

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/462923/java-embedded-databases-comparison

Comment: @MedvedievV. Thank you, I didn't know the right language to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a database written in pure Java that you can include with your app. H2 and Derby are two such products. The database files can be created and stored on the user’s local machine.

Personally, I use and recommend H2.

Comment: Thank you! I have only been a light user of databases until now, so I thought everything was "standalone" the way a MySQL install is, and I wasn't sure what made something like H2 different.