# Wrap up a simple database with a Java SE application

Tags: java, database, deployment, installation, desktop-application

I really like the way adobe has integrated sqlLite into their AIR api.  I'd love to utilize similar functionality in a Java SE 7 desktop application I'm currently coding.  Can anyone recommend a simple third party library for this?  I'm not doing anything heavy duty with it -- just to keep track of user accounts, pws, plus a few other data items.

Comment: Third party library for what, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Java Web Start](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) can provide a painless install experience for the end user.

For the database, call the installer from an extension declared as an `installer-desc`, and it will be called the first time the app. is downloaded.  Here is a [demo. of the `ExtensionInstallerService`](http://pscode.org/jws/api.html#eis).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a discussion on SO about 3 different embedded databases, [Derby](http://db.apache.org/derby/) (which [Java DB](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/overview/index.html) is based on), [H2](http://h2database.com/html/main.html), and [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/).

[Embedded java databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57102/embedded-java-databases)

Answer (score 0):

There several embedded databases you could use such as HSQL DB or Apache Derby.  I believe it is also possible to use SQLite as well.

Also, if the data is extremely simple perhaps a simple XML/flat file storage system could work equally well.